# How are these quotient groups the same?

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation

From Rotman's Algebraic Topology:  In the red box of the below picture, how did the author get from the left side to the right side?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the differential $D$ is defined on $A_i\otimes G_j$ as $D_n(a_i\otimes g_j)=da_i\otimes g_j +(-1)^ia_i\otimes \partial g_j,$ then that means that on the whole of $(A_*\otimes G_*)_n = \displaystyle \bigoplus_i A_i\otimes G_{n-i}$ that we can just sum the componentwise differentials:

$$
D_n = \sum_i d_i\otimes 1 + (-1)^i1\otimes\partial_{n-i}
$$.

When we take the quotient $\ker D_n/\text{im } D_{n+1}$, because of the grading we may take it termwise.

Comment: So $\frac{ker D_n}{im D_{n+1}} = \frac{\ker \sum_i (1 \otimes \partial_{n-1})}{\text{im }(\sum_i 1 \otimes \partial_{n+1-i})} = \sum_i (\frac{ \ker 1 \otimes \partial_{n-1}}{\text{im }1 \otimes \partial_{n+1-i}})$?

Comment: What do you mean by "because of the grading"?

Comment: In general, we cannot say that $(A\oplus B)/(C\oplus D) = A/C \oplus B/D.$ However in a graded abelian group $(A_0 \oplus A_1)/(C_0 \oplus ) = A_0/C_0\oplus A_1/C_1$. Because if we assume the map $C_0\oplus C_1\to A_0\oplus A_1$ is graded (of grading $0$), then it takes $C_0$ into $A_0$ and $C_1$ into $A_1$. That's what's happening here.